# Biztalk SOAP Adapter Maximum Number Of Messages

Tags: .net, performance, biztalk, esb

I wonder if anyone can help. We're going through a period of performance testing whereby we send messages from .Net code into a SOAP adapter exposed by Biztalk. We're having some issues when we try to send 100 messages over (sequentially) at the same time.

Our Biztalk 'expert' has came back and suggested that the Biztalk SOAP adapter may not be able to handle that many requests in quick succession. This sounds ludicrous to me, can anybody point me at any official figures regarding request thresholds / or share their experience.

(Understand WCF may be a better option, however this is not available to us at this time).

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be related to a threading, see section: Threading Issues, or a connections, see section: ASP .NET Settings Related to HTTP, SOAP, or WSE Adapter Performance at [Troubleshooting BizTalk Server SOAP Adapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dd297484%28v=BTS.10%29.aspx)